# HTML copy and paste function, replace <br> tags with linebreaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, copy, clipboard

Here is my copy funciton:

```
function myFunction(val, event) {
    var inp = document.createElement('input');
    document.body.appendChild(inp)
    inp.value = val.replace("<p>", "").replace("</p>", "").replace(/<br *\/?>/g, "\r\n");
    inp.select();
    document.execCommand('copy', false);
    inp.remove();
    alert('copied');
}
```

HTML:

```
<td>{{ resp|escape|linebreaks }}</td>
<td>{{ resp.Question_id.Statement }}</td>
<td><button onclick="myFunction('{{resp|escape|linebreaks}}')">Copy text</button></td>
```

The text I am copying contains html tags in them. I've managed to get rid of them but for <\br> tags i want to replace them with newline break \n. But my function is only removing <\br> without adding a new line.

Sample:
    <\p>Testing testing testing.<\br />something here<\br />something there<\br />)

Result:
    Testing testing testing.something heresomething there

Expected:
    Testing testing testing.
something here
something there

Comment: Why did you add python and django tags but there's no code related?

Comment: this project is using django framework so i thought to include it in the tags

Comment: You have a single file that you want to change, or it's dinamically? I ask because you can accomplish this with any text editor.